# How can I make IE stop "correcting" 'int i;' to 'int I;' when I type code on SE sites?

Tags: windows-8, spell-check, internet-explorer-10, markdown, autocorrect

Gagh! It'd be funny if it weren't so infuriating. I like spell-checking for English. It's really nice when you can't quite remember whether there is 1 'r' or 2 in "assurance", say. But after I've typed '`' (backquote) I don't want any help with screwing my code! I can screw it up on my own. Has any one else been irritated enough to figure this out already?

Comment: What are you using to do the spell checking? I am running IE9 x64 on Windows 7 Home Premium x64. I use spell checker on *"Google Toolbar"*, and I get no such correction or suggested-correction for `int i;`. On the other hand, I can type a lower-case i anywhere, and it will also not attempt to correct it to an upper-case I.

Comment: It's IE10 x64 on Windows 8. I can't find any settings or options related to this. It's whatever it was preconfigured with (presumably by Toshiba).

Comment: IE or other spell checkers obviously don't know that backquote implies code in markdown. See the answer to my question [here](http://superuser.com/questions/497391) and try adding the words to the excluded list.

Answer (score 0):

As described more fully in the linked answers, windows 8 includes a spell-checker that applies to all system-derived text-input widgets. But you can adjust the rules for a word by right-clicking on the word to bring up the context menu which includes a portion controlling the spell-checker.