# Is it possible to preload the spell check dictionary in Internet Explorer (10 & 11)?

Tags: internet-explorer, spell-check

I'm working with a client that would like to use the built-in Internet Explorer spell check to help their staff with some complex legal and medical terms. We have a list of words, and what we'd like to do is preload the user's browser dictionary so that we can skip each user having to add each word, and avoid the likely errors that may have.

I'd also consider a browser add-in or adding a custom language, but I haven't be able to find anything for the first or much detail for the latter.

Comment: Does this help http://superuser.com/questions/497391/how-to-edit-the-system-user-dictionary-in-windows-8

Comment: It does! Thanks, I'd seen that question, but thought it was Win 8 specific. Should this question be closed as a duplicate or just deleted?